# QtConcurrent gives errors

Tags: c++, qt

Given the code below, I get the following errors:

> fileio.cpp:47: error: C3867: 'FileIO::read': non-standard syntax; use
>   '&' to create a pointer to member
>
> fileio.cpp:47: error: C2780: 'QFuture
>   QtConcurrent::map(Iterator,Iterator,MapFunctor)': expects 3 arguments
>   - 2 provided

*Why is that?*

**fileio.h**

```
#ifndef FILEIO_H
#define FILEIO_H

#include <QtCore>

class FileIO : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_DISABLE_COPY(FileIO)

signals:
    void finished();

public slots:
     Q_INVOKABLE void cancel();

private:
    void read(QString &fileURL);

public:
    FileIO(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~FileIO();


    Q_INVOKABLE void read_b64(const QString &fileURL);

};

#endif // FILEIO_H
```

**fileio.cpp**

```
#include "fileio.h"
#include <QFile>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QThread>
#include <QtConcurrent>

FileIO::FileIO(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
{
}

FileIO::~FileIO()
{
}

void FileIO::read(QString &filePath)
{
    QByteArray finalBytes = QByteArray();

    filePath = QUrl(filePath).toLocalFile();

    QFile file(filePath);

    qDebug() << "file size: " << file.size();
    if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        finalBytes = file.readAll();
    }

    qDebug() << "byte size: " << finalBytes.length();

    //bytes.toBase64();
}


void FileIO::read_b64(const QString &filePath)
{

    QFutureWatcher<void> futureWatcher;
    QObject::connect(this, &FileIO::cancel, &futureWatcher, &QFutureWatcher<void>::cancel, Qt::UniqueConnection);
    QObject::connect(&futureWatcher, &QFutureWatcher<void>::finished, this, &FileIO::finished);


    QStringList filePaths;
    filePaths << filePath;

    QFuture<void> future = QtConcurrent::map(filePaths, this->read);

    futureWatcher.setFuture(future);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this->read` is not valid. You want to use [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) to bind the non-static member function with an instance create a callable and then call the 1st overload of [`QtConcurrent::map`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrent.html#map), taking two arguments:

```
QFuture<void> future =
    QtConcurrent::map(filePaths, std::bind(&FileIO::read, this));
```

Comment: okay simply declaring read without the class namespace (not sure the right word for that) worked. i.e. void read not void FileIO::read

Comment: @davidkomer Oops, I missed something. Now it should work with `read` being a non-static member function. Or maybe you should consider making `read` `static` member function.